# Android - LogCat

Tags: android

Could someone tell what is the error?

> 10-19 18:25:06.130: W/ResourceType(29353): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
>   10-19 18:25:06.132: D/AndroidRuntime(29353): Shutting down VM
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353): Process: br.info.agendamain, PID: 29353
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4138)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at br.info.adapters.EventoAdapters.getView(EventoAdapters.java:63)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:727)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:463)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5537)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17565)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1409)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1084)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5990)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>   10-19 18:25:06.135: E/AndroidRuntime(29353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
>   10-19 18:25:07.380: I/Process(29353): Sending signal. PID: 29353 SIG: 9

Thanks.

Comment: You referenced a nonexistant string resource. Check your R.java source for that and ensure they are all matched up with what you have in your resource folder.

Comment: Yet another common noob's mistake... You are trying to use TextView.setText with integer which is not a resource id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 63 or your EventoAdapters.java you are trying to use a resource that does not exist. Either you tried to use a your own constant instead of a constant from R, or it was only defined in a specific API or language.